# Why does this DI code declare a method-scope var and then assign it to a static, class-level object?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, simple-injector

.Net-wise, I've been stuck in 2005 until just recently. I know I have a lot of catching up to do but since I don't like inefficient code, the following code snippet (at the bottom of this question) from the SimpleInjector tutorial has me a bit stumped.

The problem is within the `BootStrapper()` method, which is used to intialize a static SimpleInjector container.

Within this method, a `var container` is declared and assigned a new `Container()`.  At the end of the method, the method-scope `container` is then assigned to the static, App level `container` variable.

Why is this done this way?  There must be a good reason for assigning the container first to a local-scope var and then, finally, assigning the var to the class-level, static Container variable.  To me, this seems like an obvious, redundant assignment, but if that's the case, I doubt anyone would do it this way.  What am I missing?

The code, below, is from the code from the SimpleInjector documentation.  I understand all of what the code is doing, I just don't understand the point of this extra `var` assignment.

```
using System.Windows;
using SimpleInjector;

public partial class App : Application
{
    private static Container container; //<-- The static, class-level variable. 
                                        //    Why not assign to it from the get-go?!

   //...snip...

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        Bootstrap();
    }

    private static void Bootstrap()
    {
        // Create the container as usual.
        var container = new Container();  //What's the point of this var?

        // Register your types, for instance:
        container.RegisterSingle<IUserRepository, SqlUserRepository>();
        container.Register<IUserContext, WpfUserContext>();

        // Optionally verify the container.
        container.Verify();

        // Store the container for use by the application.
        App.container = container;  //Couldn't we have done this from line 1 of this method?
    }
}
```

Source: [SimpleInjector - Windows Presentation Foundation Integration Guide](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Integration&referringTitle=Integration%20Guide)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the container is assigned to the static property at once, then the static property would reference a container that is not yet fully initialized, which could have unwanted consequences.

Assigning the container to the static property only when it is fully initialized prevents others from using a partially initialized container.

Comment: See my question on Kevin's post.

Comment: Multithreading is one reason, but there are more ways that other code parts could access the partially initialized object. The types registered might access it (such as WpfUserContext) and if an exception is thrown the Bootstrap method might not complete its execution and hence the partially initialized object will never become completely initialized.

Comment: Excellent (and somewhat obvious) point!  Yes, I will need to read up on that a bit further.  This is my first Dependency Injection project and I will services that will need to reference services.  I'm going to update my tags because I'm beginning to see how this does relate to SimpleInjector and DI.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know SimpleInjector, but a possible reason would be if RegisterSingle, Register or Verify can throw an exception. If one of them does, you could be left with App.Container in an invalid state, whereas doing it this way App.Container will be left either in the desired new state or will be left untouched. Provided Container is a managed type, you get strong exception safety (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety).

Comment: I had that thought, but since the method didn't have a try/catch wrapper, that didn't seem to make much since to me.  Under the current circumstances, an exception would just crash the application.

Comment: @RLH: It depends on the application type and when in the application's lifestyle that code is called if it shuts down the application's app domain. If it doesn't crash the application, every following request or operation will give a bizarre exception message that hides the actual problem. I've been bit by this myself in the past (although it wasn't a WPF application). And although the WPF application might die when the `Application.OnStartUp` fails, developers tend to copy-paste those code examples, so I think it doesn't hurt do write some code examples that are a little bit more robust :-)

Comment: The main reason for exceptions is that you don't have to handle them locally. The author of Bootstrap might not have any idea what would be an appropriate response to an exception, because [s]he has no idea what the final application is. By letting the exception propagate through the call tree, the author passes responsibility for the response to the failure to the client who is in a better position to make the call (or pass it in turn to their client, and so on). Not being wrapped in a try block is no indication that the code isn't being written with exception safety in mind.